# Ubuntu Server 2 NICs use VPN on only one of them

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, ip-routing

I have a server with two NICs, both connected to the network:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.1.255
        inet6 fe80::9618:82ff:fe37:9048  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 94:18:82:37:90:48  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 438291  bytes 66054606 (66.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1396490  bytes 1999931481 (1.9 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  

eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.1.255
        inet6 fe80::9618:82ff:fe37:9049  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 94:18:82:37:90:49  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 61399  bytes 7297765 (7.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3247  bytes 689114 (689.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 217840  bytes 55504285 (55.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 217840  bytes 55504285 (55.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The first interface (eno1) is the default gateway. I am trying to configure OpenVPN client to route only the traffic from the second interface (eno2) through the VPN. For the moment I'm using this openVPN config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote ca-toronto.privateinternetaccess.com 1198
resolv-retry infinite
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher aes-128-cbc
auth sha1
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass user.data
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify crl.rsa.2048.pem
ca ca.rsa.2048.crt
disable-occ
log-append /var/log/piavpn.log
nobind
route-noexec
```

From what I found I believe I need to set the route-noexec option in order to prevent routing all traffic through the VPN. OpenVPN adds this tunnel :

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.87.10.6  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.87.10.5
    inet6 fe80::3f6e:2346:240f:4169  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 1  bytes 44 (44.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1  bytes 48 (48.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The route list looks like this:

```
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eno1 
10.0.1.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.2 
10.0.1.0/24 dev eno2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.3 
10.87.10.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.87.10.6
```

I guess I have to route all traffic from eno2 to tun0 however I have no idea of how I should proceed. In the end, I'd like that all traffic using eno2 pass through the VPN and that eno1 remains as it is.